# Collapsing Group in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I am trying to collapse the previous expanded group after expanding another group. There are a lot of tutorials here but for java and none for c#. Can someone please show me how to implement in on C#, specifically Xamarin?
My ExpandableListViewAdapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using static Android.Widget.ExpandableListView;
using Java.Util.Zip;

namespace BarStar
{
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter, IFilterable
{
    private Context context;
    public List<string> listGroup;
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild;
    private GroupFilter _filter;
    private int previousItem;
    private ExpandableListView _list;



    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listGroup = listGroup;
        this.listChild = listChild;
        _filter = new GroupFilter(this);

}
    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild, ExpandableListView list) : this(context, listGroup, listChild)
    {

        _list = list; 
    }
    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return listGroup.Count;
        }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Filter Filter => _filter;

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result[childPosition];
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result.Count;
    }

    public override void OnGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition)
    {
        base.OnGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    public override void OnGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
    {
        if (groupPosition != previousItem)
        {
            _list.CollapseGroup(previousItem);

        }
        previousItem = groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Children, null);
            }
            if (isLastChild == true)
            {
                EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
                Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
                Submit.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                button.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
                textViewItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else
            {
                TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
                EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
                Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
                button.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                Submit.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                textViewItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                string content = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                textViewItem.Text = content;
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return listGroup[groupPosition];
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Groups, null);
        }
        string textGroup = (string)GetGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView textViewGroup = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Header);
        textViewGroup.Text = textGroup;
        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
    long id)
    {
        parent.SmoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

        if (parent.IsGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
        {
            parent.CollapseGroup(groupPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            parent.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);
        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

}

I just editted this and added the adapter. Everything works fine but the collapsing part.

EDIT:

This is my Main:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net;
using Java.Lang;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Util;
using System.Threading;
using Org.Json;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp.Extensions.MonoHttp;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Util;

namespace BarStar
{
[Activity(Label = "BarStar", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/logo")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private ExpandableListView list;
    private ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private int length;
    private List<string> group = new List<string>();
    private string[] names;
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Mapout = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private SearchView searchBar;
    private int length2;
    private EditText Submit;
    public string nameholder;
    private Button profileButton;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Hide();
        // Set Views
        searchBar = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchBar);
        list = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.lv);
        Submit = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
        var profileButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.profileButton);
        profileButton.Click += ProfileButton_Click;

        //Set Groups
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("https://******");
        JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray(json);
        length = myarray.Length();
        names = new string[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            JSONObject Element = myarray.GetJSONObject(i);
            names[i] = Element.GetString("name");
        }
        setData(out mAdapter);
        list.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        searchBar.QueryTextChange += searchBar_QueryTextChange;

    }

    private void ProfileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Works");
        StartActivity(typeof(ProfileActivity));
    }


private void searchBar_QueryTextChange(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        mAdapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);
    }

    private void setData(out ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter)
    {
        string urlholder;
        string url;
        string json;
        string time;
        string timestamp;
        string together;
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            List<string> listplaceholder = new List<string>();
            group.Add(names[i]);
            urlholder = Uri.EscapeDataString(names[i]);
            url = "*********" + urlholder + ".json";
            json = client1.DownloadString(url);
            JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(json);
            length2 = array2.Length();
            for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
            {


                JSONObject Element = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
                time = Element.GetString("wait");
                JSONObject TimeElement = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
                timestamp = TimeElement.GetString("created_at");
                timestamp = timestamp.Replace("T", " at ");
                int index = timestamp.IndexOf(".");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    timestamp = timestamp.Substring(0, index);
                }
                together = time + " minutes posted at " + timestamp;
                listplaceholder.Add(together);

            }
            Mapout.Add(group[i], listplaceholder);


        }
        mAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, Mapout,list);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @SushiHangover I edited my question with the given code

Comment: @SushiHangover I think the problem is that the expandablelistview list isn't actually set. Can you help me? Very stuck..

Comment: @SushiHangover Checkout the complete example here
https://github.com/away168/ExpandableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please show me how to implement in on C#, specifically Xamarin?

You need to override your adapter's `OnGroupExpanded` and collapse the last opened group there, modify your adapter's constructor to accept it's ExpandableListView and also create an index for last opened group:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter,IFilterable
{

  ...
  //this adapter's applied expandablelistview
  private ExpandableListView _exListView;
  //the index for last opened group
  private int _lastExpandGroupPosition;

  public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild)
  {
     this.context = context;
     this.listGroup = listGroup;
     this.listChild = listChild;
     _filter = new GroupFilter(this);
  }

  //create a constructor to accept the expandablelistview and reuse the original constructor
  public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild, ExpandableListView exListview) : this(context, listGroup, listChild)
  {
      _exListView = exListview;
  }

  //override OnGroupExpanded to collapse the last opened group
  public override void OnGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
  {
      if (groupPosition != _lastExpandGroupPosition)
      {
          _exListView.CollapseGroup(_lastExpandGroupPosition);

      }
      _lastExpandGroupPosition = groupPosition;
  }
 ...
}
```

And here is the modified demo:[ExpandableListViewDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/ExpandableListViewDemo/tree/master/ExpandableListViewDemo).

Comment: I am getting the error "not set in the instance of an object"

Comment: public bool onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
        long id)
        {
            parent.SmoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

            if (parent.IsGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
            {
                parent.CollapseGroup(groupPosition);
            }// I get the null reference here
            else
            {
                parent.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);
            } 

            return true;
        }

Comment: Please use the new constructor to create this adapter in your activity like this: adapter=new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this,listGroup, listChild, mexListview) ;

Comment: When I put that in it says it doesnt have a context. when I give it a expandablelistviewadapter context it wont let me pass "this" because it cant convert from context to expadablelistviewadapter. not sure whats going on with it

Comment: It is still coming up with  a null reference error. I am not sure why, code is completely the same as yours.  My code is getting the error at the OnExpanded function inside the if statement after the Collapse method

Comment: Could you share your project through github?

Comment: I could edit this one and add my MainActivity? I just have some links on there that I can not share over online.

Comment: OK, please edit this question and add your main activity.

Comment: Edited and changed the previous ExapndableListViewAdapter activity with the new one from here

Comment: Could you please debug your codes to check which variable is null?

Comment: 09-25 22:10:50.072 I/Choreographer( 3126): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I found this in debug.. Did not find anything with null

Comment: it's just unrelated stuff, the null object should be where you are getting the exception.

Comment: So it seems that it was not working because I was not in fast debugg development mode.. it started working when I turned it on.. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't think it is related, maybe your previous build is chached, which leads to a null reference. You can try turn off the fast debug development mode, and check if you still get the error. And please clear the complete project and rebuild.

Comment: It is working now off fast debug mode.. I have no idea what happened and how it got fixed.